# How to rewrite 2 urls with same number of parameters?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We trying to rewrite two urls with same number of parameters, given below.

```
 URL 1: www.build99.com/5/Electricals
 URL 2: www.build99.com/10/Civil

 Re-Written URL 1: http://www.build99.com/flooringmain.php?maincatid=5&catname=Electricals
 Re-Written URL 2: http://www.build99.com/flooringmain1.php?catid=10&subname=Civil
```

.htaccess file written as given below

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /buildnin/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /flooringmain.php?maincatid=$1&catname=$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /flooringmain1.php?catid=$1&subname=$2 [L]
```

But we could not able to find the results corrects, please suggest us what have we done wrong with the above url?

Comment: You cannot. Since pattern `^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$` will match both URLs

Comment: So... What can i do for this.. any suggestions..?

Comment: Use a prefix for one like `www.build99.com/floor/10/Civil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.. Have Found it..

I have updated the Pattern for the second rule.. Just used '-' between the two argument patterns.. its working great.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /flooringmain.php?maincatid=$1&catname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /flooringmain1.php?catid=$1&subname=$2 [L]
```